# NAN Error When Adding Percentage Sign to JS

Tags: javascript, php

On one of my websites, [www.makememodern.com](http://www.makememodern.com), there is a section (What We Do) that displays numbers that rapidly increase until they reach a defined number. I am wanting to place the "%" with the larger orange numbers, but it results with "NAN".

Here is what I found in the Shortcode.php file related to this section:

```
function rocknrolla_milestone_box_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ){

    extract( shortcode_atts(array(
        "count" => '500',       
        "title" => ''
    ), $atts) );   

    $rnr_milestone_box = '<div class="milestone-counter" data-perc="'. $count .'">';
    $rnr_milestone_box .= '<span class="milestone-count highlight">'. $count .'</span>';
    $rnr_milestone_box .= '<h6 class="milestone-details">'. $title .'</h6>';
    $rnr_milestone_box .= '</div>';

    return $rnr_milestone_box;
}
```

I found this in the scripts.js file that is related to the section I'm having trouble with:

```
jQuery('.milestone-counter').appear(function() {
    jQuery('.milestone-counter').each(function(){
        dataperc = jQuery(this).attr('data-perc'),
        jQuery(this).find('.milestone-count').delay(6000).countTo({
        from: 0,
        to: dataperc,
        speed: 2000,
        refreshInterval: 100
    });
```

Comment: "NAN" keyword is more common in Javascript rather than PHP. I don't think your issue come from PHP. I bet on the "data-perc" HTML attribute which count be not read as expected by the Javascript

Comment: `$rnr_milestone_box .='<span class="milestone-count highlight">'. $count .'%</span>';` Does changing this piece of code results in as expected ?

Comment: Just changed the code. It flashes the percentage sign for a second, but then disappears.

Comment: Show us your JavaScript code... try turning off JS in your browser and see if that "fixes" the issue..

Comment: JS code has been added to original post.

Comment: FYI: Seems like this plugin is involved, link maybe useful to others trying to assist: https://github.com/mhuggins/jquery-countTo

Comment: Have you tried placing the percentage sign outside of span.milestone-count? i.e. `'</span>%'`.

Comment: Turning off the JS in Chrome "fixed" the problem.

Comment: Alternatively you could use the `formatter` option of the `countTo` plugin... `formatter: function(value, options){return value + '%';}` should work? Add it to the array map with `to`, `from` etc

Comment: I changed the code to `</span>%` and it added the percentage sign, but it is small. It's much appreciated progress, but is there any way to may it the same as the orange number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$rnr_milestone_box .= '<span class="milestone-count highlight"><span class="milestone-count-percent">'. $count .'</span>%</span>';
...
jQuery(this).find('.milestone-count-percent').delay(6000).countTo({
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest hack I can think of without any JS wrangling..see if this works.

```
function rocknrolla_milestone_box_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ){

    extract( shortcode_atts(array(
        "count" => '500',       
        "title" => ''
    ), $atts) );   

    $rnr_milestone_box = '<div class="milestone-counter" data-perc="'. $count .'">';
     $rnr_milestone_box .='<span class="milestone-count highlight">'. $count .'</span>';
    $rnr_milestone_box .='<span class="highlight" style="font-family: \'Open Sans\', \'Times New Roman\', Times, serif;font-size: 80px;line-height: 1.2;padding: 0;margin-bottom: 20px;position: relative;font-weight:700;text-transform: uppercase;letter-spacing: -0.02em;">%</span>';
    $rnr_milestone_box .= '<h6 class="milestone-details">'. $title .'</h6>';
    $rnr_milestone_box .= '</div>';

    return $rnr_milestone_box;
}
```